# open and run the sql file from network drive in sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to run the file from network drive but getting error message as `Unable to open file`.

I am trying below command to run in sql developer :

```
@\\chllrog.amastre.com\Shares\test\execute_report.sql
```

I also tried like this below but getting same error message:

```
@"\\chllrog.amastre.com\Shares\test\execute_report.sql"
```

When i open the execute_report.sql file from this location and execute the contents of the file which creates new excel file in the same directory then its creating new file and its working.

Comment: are those slashes the right way round?

Comment: i am not sure is it not the right way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use network map for your operating system (in Windows, right click the shared folder in explorer and `Map Network Drive`). Then you can run the script from SQL Developer using the mapped drive, for example: `@z:\Shares\test\execute_report.sql`

You can use the same addressing of file for spool and output file

Answer (score 0):

It did work for me without drive mapping:

```
sqlplus /nolog "@\\server\path\file.sql"
```

sqlplus version 12.2.0.1
The quotes and '@' are important, apparently.